# How do I use BrowserRouter in next.js without getting error?

Tags: next.js, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use `BrowserRouter` in my Next.js web app to route between different pages based on whether or not a user is logged in which I check by looking at my global state variable `user` through my `useAuthContext` hook that I made. Currently, I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at getUrlBasedHistory (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\@remix-run\router\dist\router.cjs.js:380:14)
    at Object.createBrowserHistory (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\@remix-run\router\dist\router.cjs.js:207:10)
    at BrowserRouter (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-router-dom\dist\umd\react-router-dom.development.js:256:35)
    at processChild (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3043:14)
    at resolve (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2960:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3435:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
    at renderToString (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3988:27)
    at Object.renderPage (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:50:851)
    at Function.getInitialProps (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\.next\server\pages\_document.js:299:19)
```

I don't know why there's an error happening, here is the code to my `index.js` file which is where I put the `BrowserRouter` routing code:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthContext } from 'hooks/useAuthContext';
import HomePage from './home';
import ProductPage from './product';
import LoginPage from './login';
import SignupPage from './signup';

export default function IndexPage() {
  const { user } = useAuthContext()

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route 
              path="/" 
              element={<HomePage />} 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/login" 
              element={!user ? <LoginPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/signup" 
              element={!user ? <SignupPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/product" 
              element={!user ? <ProductPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `react-router-dom` in a Next.js app. Next.js provide its own built-in router. See https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need all this unnecessary tools in a great framework like Next.js

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

Try and go through [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction)

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link href="/">
  <a>Home</a>
</Link>
```

Using Conditionals

```
<Link href={!user ? "/loginPage" : "/"}>
  <a>{!user ? "Login" : "Home"}</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: How would I perform the operations I have listed above with `<Link>`?

Comment: I just updated the code to include conditionals, you can use pure js to route to a componnt not Link

Comment: I was so stuck with this 'document' that I didn't even know how to search for an answer, but this was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much, it worked like a charm!